# How to pass class member function as Handler function

Tags: c++, esp8266

on ESP8266 WiFi board I set up an ESP8266 Webserver. Without organizing my code in classes, this works pretty well. I am able to tell my Web-server Instance what method it should call on a specific URI doing this:

```
ESP8266WebServer server(80);
void handleRoot(){ // do sth}
server.on("/root", handleRoot)
```

However, now I want to refactor my code, to hide more complex operations within objects and operate on those objects only. Unfortunately I am no able to set a Class-Function as a Handler-Function. It would work for a static, method, but this does not help as there i cannot refer to variables of my object. I do not want to make the server variable a static variable. 
Is there a possible solution? Or how would you implement this in a nice way.

Header File:

```
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

class my_WebServer
{
  ESP8266WebServer* server;

public:
  my_WebServer();    
  void setup();    

  void handleRoot1(ESP8266WebServer* server);
  static  void handleRoot1(ESP8266WebServer* server);

};
```

.cpp File:

```
//Constructor
my_WebServer::my_WebServer(){
  server = new ESP8266WebServer(80);
  setup();
}

void my_WebServer::handleRoot1(){
  // do sth
  server->send(404, "text/plain", "random text);
}

void my_WebServer::handleRoot2(){
  // do sth
  server->send(404, "text/plain", "random text);      //does not work, as "server" is not avaliable in static method
}

void my_WebServer::setup(){
  server->on("/root1", server->handleRoot1);           // does not work
  server->on("/root2", ESP8266WebServer::handleRoot2); // works
}
```

Relating Informations:
class Index: https://links2004.github.io/Arduino/index.html

Comment: okay, I just made it work, with the help of this post: [link](http://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=4505), so I use `server->on("/", std::bind(&my_WebServer::handleRoot, this));`

Comment: But what exactly am i doing it, can you give me a buzzword that i can look up this in a c++ tutorial or sth? Also is this a nice way of solving my issue or would you not organize a third party class within your own class?

Comment: Basically you are telling the compiler you want the adress of your member function - `&my_WebServer::handleRoot` (that is its like a pointer - the adress in memory where your function is stored so that `server->on()` knows how to call it - be bound to an object (`this`), so that when the function is called, it has access to e.g. the `server` variable with its current value. If it were not a class member but a global function, this would not be neccessary and you could just use `&handleRoot` , because there is no object with certain variables that the function needs to know to work properly.